# Relationships with different name than the standard on ActiveRecord migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have generated three models (rails generate model): Professionals, ProfessionalCouncils and States. The Professionals table must have a reference to the States table, but the column should be named professional_council_state_id instead of state_id.

How can I achieve this in my migration code?

Here is how it is right now:

```
class CreateProfessionals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :professionals do |t|
      t.string :name, limit: 70
      t.string :number, limit: 15

      t.references :professional_council, index: true
      t.references :occupation_code, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :professionals, :professional_councils

    add_foreign_key :professionals, :occupation_codes
  end
end


class CreateStates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :states do |t|
      t.string :description, limit: 40, null: false
      t.string :abbreviation, limit: 2, null: false
      t.integer :ibge_code

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what column name you want `state_id` **OR** `professional_council_state_id`

Comment: professional_council_state_id

Comment: instead of `t.references` you can use `t.integer :professional_council_state_id`

Comment: But it have to create a foreign key to the States in the Professionals table. Will it work this way?

Comment: try to replace this `add_foreign_key :professionals, :professional_councils` with `add_foreign_key :professionals, :professional_council_state_id`

Comment: Actually what I had to do is `add_foreign_key :professionals, :states, column: :professional_council_state_id`